# PSR-4 Custom namespace for any vendor library added

Tags: php, autoloader, psr-4

Can we add custom namespace in psr-4 autoloader for any vendor library we have, for example if we require any library in composer.phar and then we give path of the library which is in vendor folder ? Can we give it custom namespace and can it work like MycustomNS/LibraryOrigNS ? Is it possible ? Any Idea.

What I'm Doing ..

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "myCustomNS\\": "vendor/lusitanian/oauth/src"
    }
}
```

After that I can access the namespace in index.php file like below

`index.php` file code...

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; //this will load the composer.phar as we know

$new = new \myCustomNS\LibraryOrigNS;
```

Thanks
Adil